# strstr() function in C

Tags: c, arrays, strstr

I am a new learner and want to output a fill truth array use strstr() in C.

There are three keyword groups in lists with different size need to compare.

```
keywords group 1: foo1,foo2. Stored in truth[0],truth[1].
keywords group 2: bar1,bar2,bar3,bar4.Stored in truth[2] to truth[5]. 
keywords group 3: baz1,baz2,baz3,baz4,....Stored in truth[6] to truth[k-1].
```

All members in the truth array were set to a mask number (like -1) at the beginning assuming the input does not have any keywords. If the input matches any keyword in a keyword group, then the element in that group should set to 1 and all other elements in the same keywords group need set to 0. I also want to check that there is at most one keyword from each keyword group.

For example:

```
input:"bar1"; output:[-1,-1, 1,0,0,0,  -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,....]; 
input:"foo1_baz5"; output:[1,0, -1,-1,-1,-1, 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,...];
input:"foo1_bar1_baz1"; output:[1,0, 1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...];
input:"foo1_foo2"; output:"too many keywords".
```

This is the code I have worked so far (let's say total 100 keywords in the lists):

```
void fill_truth(char input, char *lists, int *truth)
{
    int i;
    int truth[100];
    memset(truth, -1, 100*sizeof(int));
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        if(strstr(input, lists[i])){
            truth[i] = 1;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    if(count > 3) printf("too many keywords: %d, %s\n", count, input);
}
```

How to modify the code that strstr can set others to 0 and check if no more than one keyword from the same group? Thanks for your help!

Update 1: Sorry for the format issue, here -1 is just a mask number, you may use any other integers other than 1, and 0.

Ｕpdate 2: Right now I am able to set others to 0 using 3 loops and also can check the total number of keywords, the only issue I have at the moment is that it will give -nan if I set all initial values to -1. I also tried some other integers, but it overrides by 0 whatever initial value I set. Any hint about why this happens and which initial value I should set as a mask at the beginning?

Update3: Sorry for misunderstanding due to posting several variations of the code when updating. I already figured this out, and thanks for everyone who spent their time in answering my question!

Comment: Any reason your truth table is `float` and not `int`? You have K to determine how many lists you have, but you also need to keep track of how many keywords in each group, no?

Comment: no need to track k, k is about 100. you can make k as int instead of float

Comment: "truth array were set to -1" and `float *truth` and `memset(truth, -1, k*sizeof(float));` is questionable.  The value of `truth[i]` is not -1.

Comment: ... in fact my test shows `-nan`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, see my update2, which secret number I should use?

Comment: Now you changed `float` to `int` why should there be an issue with `-1`? Why does your "Update 2" still talk about `nan`? You have posted several variations of the code, but it is unclear what you are now asking. This no tutorial site.

Comment: Also, you mention *"If input match any keyword in a* ***group***, but you have no way to correlate what **group** any match of `list[i]` applies to? Maybe I'm just missing it....